# get the source code from an APK file back - the notebook drive crashed

Tags: java, apk

The notebook drive on my laptop just crashed and all the data are lost. 
Belive it or not: I have lost all the source-code for an app that I have been working on for several months. 
All I have is the APK file that i have mailed to a friend. In other words - i have stored the data in this apk - file.

Well - it seems that i can start at the very beginning.Or is there any way to extract my source code from this APK file again.

In other words -can i find a starting point to work on.

Which tools can i use to gather the data that i  might have lost.

Comment: Have you ever considered .apk decompilers? Just google it, it is not that hard!

Comment: You should start using VCS like git.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try decompiling your APK using [ClassyShark](https://github.com/google/android-classyshark). Another good tool is [Apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/).